# How to set print orientation to landscape

Tags: java, jasper-reports, orientation

I am using *iReport 5.1.0* and *JasperReports Server 5*. I was able to set the report page size orientation to *Landscape* and was able to preview the report in *Landscape*. But my problem is when exporting it to *Docx* or *RTF*, when printing the report, the print preview and printing of the report is in portrait, making the actual report cut. How do I set up the print orientation of my *jrxml* file or how do I make the printing *landscape*?

Comment: What is your code (*Java* and *jrxml*)?

Comment: Im using JapserServer to generate the report. I upload a jrxml file to the jasperserver.